# Getting the excel file after df.to_excel(...) with Panda

Tags: python, excel, pandas, firebase, writer

I am using Pyrebase to upload my files to Firebase.

I have a DataFrame `df` and convert it to an Excel File as follows:

```
writer      = ExcelWriter('results.xlsx')
excelFile   = df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

print(excelFile)

# Save to firebase
childRef        = "path/to/results.xlsx"

storage         = firebase.storage()
storage.child(childRef).put(excelFile)
```

However, this stores the Excel file as an Office Spreadsheet with zero bytes. If I run `writer.save()` then I do get the appropriate filetype (`xlsx`), but it is stored on my Server (which I want to avoid). How can I generate the right filetype as one would do with `writer.save()`?

Note: `print(excelFile)` returns `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by using local memory:

```
# init writer
bio         = BytesIO()
writer      = pd.ExcelWriter(bio, engine='xlsxwriter')
filename    = "output.xlsx"

# sheets
dfValue.to_excel(writer, "sheetname")

# save the workbook
writer.save()
bio.seek(0)      

# get the excel file (answers my question)          
workbook    = bio.read()  
excelFile   = workbook

# save the excelfile to firebase
# see also issue: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/142
timestamp       = str(int(time.time()*1000));
childRef        = "/path/to/" + filename

storage         = firebase.storage()
storage.child(childRef).put(excelFile)
fileUrl         = storage.child(childRef).get_url(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should add

```
writer.save()
```

*[source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)*

Comment: yes, but then it saves it on my server. I only want to get the Excel Object into my (short term) memory and use it to store it on Firebase and not on my server.

E.g. when you use FileReader in Javascript, it creates a File Blob. This you can input to save externally.

Comment: Can you then try `storage.child(childRef).put(writer.save())`

Comment: Tried. Not working. I also tried .put(df) but that did not work. There must be a way to get the File Object.

Comment: I think because Pyrebase is an API wrapper, you'll have to materialize the file to upload it. You can then delete it after the upload is sucessful.